# str_replace remove any character not in array

Tags: php, transliteration

Hello I have this function which replace's greek characters with latin characters

```
function greeklish($Name) 
{  
$greek   = array('α','ά','Ά','Α','β','Β','γ', 'Γ', 'δ','Δ','ε','έ','Ε','Έ','ζ','Ζ','η','ή','Η','θ','Θ','ι','ί','ϊ','ΐ','Ι','Ί', 'κ','Κ','λ','Λ','μ','Μ','ν','Ν','ξ','Ξ','ο','ό','Ο','Ό','π','Π','ρ','Ρ','σ','ς', 'Σ','τ','Τ','υ','ύ','Υ','Ύ','φ','Φ','χ','Χ','ψ','Ψ','ω','ώ','Ω','Ώ',' ',"'","'",','); 
$english = array('a', 'a','A','A','b','B','g','G','d','D','e','e','E','E','z','Z','i','i','I','th','Th', 'i','i','i','i','I','I','k','K','l','L','m','M','n','N','x','X','o','o','O','O','p','P' ,'r','R','s','s','S','t','T','u','u','Y','Y','f','F','ch','Ch','ps','Ps','o','o','O','O','_','_','_','_'); 
$string  = str_replace($greek, $english, $Name); 
return $string; 
} 
echo greeklish("Το ελληνικό κείμενο εδώ");
```

I was wondering if there is a quick way to modify this function in order to replace / remove any character found in `$Name` that is not in `$greek` array with `''`

**UPDATE**

I forgot to mention that in Greece there is a way of typing (mostly used among people of younger age) were they type Greek words using Latin characters. Also there is not something standard for example:

`'ει'` `'υ'` `'ι'` `'οι'` `'η'` sound like `'e'`

`'θ'` can be written like `'th'` or `'8'` or even `'3'`

so a custom algorithm is needed for this conversion.

Comment: [iconv](http://www.php.net/manual/ro/book.iconv.php) is a set of functions meat for converting a string from one collation/encoding to another. It has a "transliteration" option which replaces a character from a collation with the equivalent character from the other collation.

Comment: @GolezTrol there's the "translit" option as described in the manual "If you append the string //TRANSLIT to out_charset transliteration is activated. This means that when a character can't be represented in the target charset, it can be approximated through one or several similarly looking characters. If you append the string //IGNORE, characters that cannot be represented in the target charset are silently discarded. Otherwise, str is cut from the first illegal character and an E_NOTICE is generated.".

Comment: @Mihai Doesn't really do the job though: http://3v4l.org/jkq3A. Not sure if iconv can do the same mapping.

Comment: @deceze I remember working with it for German and French -- had these kinds of weird problems with it too, it took a lot of trial and error to get it working including various attempts at `setlocale` but it did work in the end (for the most part).

Comment: @deceze it's true that in German and French the characters being transliterated weren't normal characters mapped with the same character-point in ASCII, they were the respective languages'  diacritical characters.

Comment: @Mihai Yeah, mapping an "ä" to an "a" is pretty straight forward. However "β" to "b" is pretty arbitrary, don't know if this relationship is specified officially anywhere.

Comment: @deceze I tried out a bit of code to get the `mb_ord`/`mb_chr` of each character in the text and substract the difference between `a` and `α`. I wanted to check if the alphabets are (by chance) just offset by a fixed value. But they aren't :-).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd suggest this:

```
$regex  = sprintf('/[^%s]/u', preg_quote(join($greek), '/'));
$string = preg_replace($regex, '', $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have it as a parameter:

```
function greeklish($Name, $invert=false) 
{  
   $greek   = array('α','ά','Ά','Α','β','Β','γ', 'Γ', 'δ','Δ','ε','έ','Ε','Έ','ζ','Ζ','η','ή','Η','θ','Θ','ι','ί','ϊ','ΐ','Ι','Ί', 'κ','Κ','λ','Λ','μ','Μ','ν','Ν','ξ','Ξ','ο','ό','Ο','Ό','π','Π','ρ','Ρ','σ','ς', 'Σ','τ','Τ','υ','ύ','Υ','Ύ','φ','Φ','χ','Χ','ψ','Ψ','ω','ώ','Ω','Ώ',' ',"'","'",','); 
   if($invert)
   {
      return preg_replace('/[^'.preg_quote(join('', $greek), '/').']/', '', $Name);
   }
   $english = array('a', 'a','A','A','b','B','g','G','d','D','e','e','E','E','z','Z','i','i','I','th','Th', 'i','i','i','i','I','I','k','K','l','L','m','M','n','N','x','X','o','o','O','O','p','P' ,'r','R','s','s','S','t','T','u','u','Y','Y','f','F','ch','Ch','ps','Ps','o','o','O','O','_','_','_','_'); 
   $string  = str_replace($greek, $english, $Name); 
   return $string; 
} 

echo greeklish("Το ελληνικό κείμενο εδώ", 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help you:

```
$string = preg_replace("/[^\p{Greek}]+/u", '', $string);
```

, or as HamZa mentioned:

```
$string = preg_replace("/\P{Greek}+/u", '', $string);
```

Comment: You might use `/\P{Greek}/u`